# Magento Add new Fields In Customer Address?

Tags: shipping-address, customer-address

I want to add new field Title. This field is a Dropdown and I give value like this.

```
$attributes = array(
'jobtitle'           => array(
    'label'    => 'Title',
    'backend_type'     => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input'    => 'select',
    'is_user_defined'   => 1,
    'is_system'         => 0,
    'is_visible'        => 1,
    'sort_order'        => 140,
    'is_required'       => 1,
    'multiline_count'   => 0,
    'option'            => array (
        'value' => array(
            'Mr' => array('Mr'),
            'Mrs' => array('Mrs'),
            'Ms' => array('Ms'),                                               
            'Miss' => array('Miss'),                                               
            'Dr' => array('Dr'),                                              
            )
    ),
    'validate_rules'    => array(
        'max_text_length'   => 255,
        'min_text_length'   => 1
    ),
),
);

foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $data) {
    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
    $attribute->setWebsite($store->getWebsite());
    $attribute->addData($data);
        $usedInForms = array(
            'adminhtml_customer_address',
            'customer_address_edit',
            'customer_register_address'
        );
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
    $attribute->save();
}
```

There is a options is my dropdown value. when I see in the admin side, field is added and the dropdown is displayed but this value is not set. I am getting the blank Dropdown. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to add title in-front of customer name, it's an in-built feature in Magento. Go to `System > Configuration`. And under Customers tab select `customer configurations`. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Thank you.Thank you. Thank you. so much thank's.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked for you :)

Comment: hi i want rename prefix to title please where i can change label prefix to title  thank's

Comment: While this hits his specific use case, it does not answer the actual question posed (which comes up in search results) - adding a select to a customer address

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `'source'` instead of `'option'` and create a source model which returns the option values.

The option structrue should look like this:

```
array(
  array(
     'label' => 'A',
     'value' => 1
  ),
  array(
     'label' => 'B',
     'value' => 2
  )
)
```